# How do I automate cross-region copying of encrypted RDS snapshots in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Doing so in the UI is very easy, just select the region and click go. Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html), it appears I need to create a pre-signed URL. However I don't see the options in the API to create this.

I’d like to do this via a Javascript AWS Lambda.

I can do this via the command line like so:

```
$  aws rds copy-db-snapshot   --source-db-snapshot-identifier arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:XXXX:snapshot:XXX-2017-01-31-04-30      --target-db-snapshot-identifier mydbsnapshotcopy   --kms-key-id XXX --region eu-central-1 --source-region eu-west-1
```

However the JavaScript APIs don't support a [SourceRegion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#copyDBSnapshot-property).

Answer (score 1):

As it clearly states in the documentation you linked, you only need to create a pre-signed URL if you are not specifying a source region. So just specify a source region.

> --source-region — The AWS region that the encrypted DB snapshot will be copied from. If source-region is not specified, you must specify a
>   pre-signed-url. A pre-signed-url is a URL that contains a Signature
>   Version 4 signed request for the CopyDBSnapshot action to be called in
>   the source region where the DB snapshot will be copied from. To learn
>   more about the pre-signed-url, see CopyDBSnapshot.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Looks like there are newer versions of the AWS CLI. I'm seeing version `1.11.29` as the newest one.

Comment: Ah. Why wasn't pip upgrading. Anyhoos. That is for the command line, not the JS API.